# Delimited files - remove beginning and trailing whitespace, and empty whitespace values (Notepad++ and Excel)

Tags: excel, notepad++

I have a file that is pipe-delimited and semi-fixed width.  What I mean by that, is that the values can look like this:

```
one|two two|three three  |  four four|     |   six six  |seven   seven
eight eight|     nine      nine    |
```

My goal is to remove all beginning whitespace, trailing whitespace, and and sections where there is whitespace in an empty delimiter (such as you see between four and six above).  Once complete, I intend to work with the file in Excel.

I know that I could tackle the whitespace by importing the entire file into Excel and performing a **TRIM()** command, but that is very time-consuming with very 'wide' documents.

My current solution is to tackle this with Notepad++ with a series of find and replace commands:

1. Trim trailing whitespace:

   - Find what: `(\S+)\s+[|]`
   - Replace with: `\1|`
2. Trim beginning whitespace:

   - Find what: `([|])\s+([A-Za-z])`
   - Replace with: `\1\2`
3. Trim whitespace from within empty columns:

   - Find what: `[|]\s+[|]`
   - Replace with: `||`

...and then import to Excel.

Is there a simpler, single find and replace command I could be using, or should I just put these together in a macro?

Comment: In Excel, you could probably use a combination of Text to Columns (using a pipe, then space as delimiter), and `Trim()`.  Are you familiar with those?

Comment: What would be your result looks like? Have you tried what @BruceWayne have suggested?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

Find what: `\s*\|\s*`
Replace with: `|`

**Edit:**
Change `\s` into `\h` to avoid matching linebreak.  `\h` stands for horizontal white space :

Find what: `\h*\|\h*`
Replace with: `|`

Comment: Followed by a replace of `[|]{2,}` with `|`, to comply with the other requirement (remove empty sections)

Comment: @Jcl: according to OP's third point, `|\s+|` must be replaced with `|`, that's what my regex is doing.

Comment: uhm, isn't it just trimming? That'd leave with `||` parts that should be converted to single `|` to remove "empty sections", wouldn't it? That'd be what mine would do after yours

Comment: I may not have been clear in my initial post, but parts where there are two pipes with zero or more spaces between should be converted to two pipes with zero spaces between.  I tested @Toto's answer and it works perfectly for this and all my other situations in the test case above.

Comment: OK, I found one issue - when @Toto finds `|\r\n`, the program will trim the end of line characters for any situation where the pipe character is the last  printable character on the line.  Instead, the find what should be `\s*\|\s*?`

Answer (score 0):

This may sound like a stupid answer but this is how I'd go about doing this.

Open replace and put "| " and in the replace put "|", hit replace until you get 0 changes.

Then do the same with " |" and in replace "|"

Finally do it with "  " (two spaces) and " " (one space).

My apologies if this isn't what you want. I can't do comments yet.